# can we provide default values to a column of a custom schema in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to pyspark, please do let me know if you have a solution for this

I created a custom schema in pyspark , like below

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
    
structureSchema = StructType([
             StructField('col1', StringType(), True),
             StructField('col2', StringType(), True),
             StructField('col3', StringType(), True)   ,
])
```

I have a text file containing multiple jsons, something like this

```py
{'col1':'abc','col2':'abc1','col3':'qwe'}
{'col1':'abc','col2':'abc1'}
{'col1':'abc''col3':'qwe'} .
```

When I load this file to the custom schema created, it fills the missing columns entries with `null` values.

```py
df = spark.read.schema(structureSchema).json(fpath)   

col1      col2     col3
abc       abc1     qwe
abc       abc1     null
abc       null     null
```

Is there a way I can fill them with a default value `"NoValueReceived"` instead of `"null"`, like below

```
col1      col2     col3
abc       abc1     qwe
abc       abc1     NoValueReceived
abc       NoValueReceived  NoValueReceived
```

Answer (score 0):

In PySpark, `DataFrame.fillna()` or `DataFrameNaFunctions.fill()` is used to replace NULL/None values on all or selected multiple DataFrame columns with either zero(0), empty string, space, or any constant literal values.

Reference:
https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-fillna-fill-replace-null-values/

```py
df = spark.read.schema(structureSchema).json(fpath)
df = df.na.fill(value="NoValueReceived",subset=["col1", "col2", "col3"])
```

Comment: Hi , sorry this doesnt work for my problem . This way it would fill all unavailable and null locations with NoValueReceived.

Consider a scenario where we receive {'col1':'abc','col3':null} . There col2 is not present and col3 has null . In the dataframe I would like to retain the value of col3 to be null itself , whereas col2 should have "NoValueReceived". I want to be able to differentiate between col2 and col3

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think you can check if you have or not that column in you incoming data, like

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce

# Read in the JSON file with a pre-defined schema
df = spark.read.json("path/to/file.json", schema=schema)

# Fill in missing values with a default value
df = df.withColumn("column_name", coalesce(df["column_name"], lit("default_value")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible if you read this data as JSON, but I have one suggestion which may work (you will need to try it).

First you would read this JSON file as text file using `df = spark.text(path)`

Now you have column value which contains row for each line. After you load it like this you may rely on spark JSON function to check if particular field exists or not in your JSON. You may use `schema_of_json` function to load schema (as struct type) with fields for each row.

Once you have that you will transform you column by adding missing fields with your default value if they don't exist.